# Finding a percent of how far away an object is in a 2D grid

Tags: java, arrays, swing

[image: annotated graph image]
For my a project for Computer Science, I am making a Maze Game. I have already coded a randomized prims algorithm for randomly making the maze and it works great.
I have added an object I would like to call a radio (shown as the yellow square in the image linked above) that plays music from it. If the player (shown as red in the image) is at [0, 0] (top left) and the radio is at [7, 4] (bottom right), I want the volume to be very quiet. If the player and radio are side by side I want the volume to be the loudest. The volume I wish to be stored in a double (ranging from 0.0 for no audio and 1.0 for full volume. How would I do this?

Comment: What is the distance between red and yellow? Is it for example a straight line, or is it the shortest path between them?

Comment: Whichever one would have a nicer scaling factor with it. I assume that would be the shortest path.

Edit: Shortest path ignoring walls is what I should have said.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the direct distance between the player and the radio, and not the distance they would have to walk in the maze, then you can just take the user's current distance as a percentage of the maximum distance.

The maximum distance is [0, 0] to [n-1, m-1], where n and m are the height and width of your grid. In your example, the radio is 7 units away horizontally, and 4 units away vertically. Applying the Pythagoras Theorem gets us ~8.06 units as the maximum distance.

The current distance is just where the user is, compared to the radio. If the user was at [3, 2], then they are 4 units away horizontally, and 2 units away vertically. Again applying the Pythagoras Theorem, the user is ~4.46 units away.

Taking that as a percentage, the user is about 55% of the maximum distance away from the radio. You can then set the volume to (100-55)% = 45%. You might also want to limit the minimum volume to maybe 20-30%, so they can hear the music even when they are just starting out.

p.s. If the steps are too big, you can maybe add a timer to transition the volume smoothly in smaller steps, instead of suddenly changing the volume.